# What is the purpose of using $db['read-write'] AND $db['read-write-create'] in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

What is the purpose of using   `$db['read-write']` AND  `$db['read-write-create']` in `database.php` (`application/config/database.php`) in Codeigniter? Please help me to get an answer .

```
$db['read-write'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'db_test',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production') ,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array() ,
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
$db['read-write-create'] = array(
    'dsn' => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => 'root',
    'database' => 'db_test',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production') ,
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array() ,
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

Comment: read this : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: Read-only replicas are often used for performance reasons or fail-over situations.

Comment: The name 'read-write' and ‘read-write-create’ is arbitrary. It can be anything you want. By default codeigniter used the word “default” for the primary connection, but it too can be renamed to something more relevant to your project.